# Define a scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator by passing `matmul` as argument

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

**Problem**

I would like to use [`scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html) to construct a linear operator of my choice that acts on a vector field.

**What I have tried**

My approach so far has been as follows (illustrating with this MRE) :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

N = 100

np.random.seed(442)
vector_field = np.random.rand(3,N**2)

def my_func(v):
    """
        Here v is a 3xN**2 array which houses my vector field.
        In my case the function has spatially dependent term
        (like divergence of the field) unlike this simple 
        algebraic case but still linear
    """
    v = v.reshape(3,N,N)
    return np.array([3*(v[0,:,:])**2,  2*v[0,:,:], - 4*v[2,:,:]]).reshape(3,N**2)
```

Since I have an array of values which returns an array of values, I passed `my_func` to the `matmat` constructor :

```
L = LinearOperator((3,3),matmat=my_func)
```

However, this returns the following error :

```
TypeError: _CustomLinearOperator.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'matvec'
```

Trying to define the `LinearOperator` by passing the custom function to the `matvec` constructor :

```
L = LinearOperator((3,3),matvec=my_func)
```

returns the obvious error message saying

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,N,N)
```

**Inferences**

1. The `matvec` argument is compulsory

**Problems**

1. How should I try to solve my problem?
2. Why isn't `matmat` a suitable constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit puzzled by the behavior with `matvec`. According to the documentation, just defining `matmat` should work.

In your case, the problem is that the shape in your constructor is not correct. `my_func` takes a vector that has shape `3*N**2` as input, I understand that `L` acts globally on this state and therefore is matrix `(3*N**2, 3*N**2)`.

The crash is due to the fact you did not provide any `dtype`. In the absence of `dtype`, the constructor guesses it by running `matvec` on a random float vector. This is why `matvec` is called in the constructor, it can be avoided by adding `dtype=float` in your input.

So an optimal solution is

```py
L = LinearOperator(shape=(3*N**2, 3*N**2), matvec=my_func, dtype=float)
```

Comment: So what's confusing is that `LinearOperator` deligates the init to `_CustomLinearOperator` which has `def __init__(self, shape, matvec, ...)`.  So while `LinearOperator` itself has `def __init__(self, dtype, shape):` signature, the subclass, with user defined methods, requires at least the `matvec`.

Comment: @hpaulj an issue was been raised a while ago [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/19213)